# Extract weekdays present in string in r

Tags: r, string

I want to extract weekdays present in string into a list. Appreciate if some one could suggest the easy way out.

```
strg <- 'Consumer   bot  --At 08:00 PM, only on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday'
```

Expecting result to be in list like: `"Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try matching all occurrences of the following pattern:

```
\b\w+day\b
```

Sample script:

```
strg <- 'Consumer   bot  --At 08:00 PM, only on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday'
m <- gregexpr("\\b\\w+day\\b", strg)
regmatches(strg, m)[[1]]

[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"
```

We could try to make the pattern more restrictive, to avoid unwanted matches such as `holiday`:

```
\b(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)day\b
```

But for your sample data, the above pattern would generate the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We can also generate all days of the week and then extract the ones that match pattern.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(strg, paste0(weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6),collapse = "|"))[[1]]
#[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"
```

`paste0` generates all days.

```
paste0(weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:6), collapse = "|") 
#[1] "Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday"
```